# Are GET queries slow in google cloud datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Number of entries is a little more than 337k, however queries to fetch even just a single entry is taking anywhere from 600-1500ms. That seems fairly high to me. Is that normal or am I doing something wrong?

The queries are made from a GAE instance in us central using a very simple Go script. Here's what dashboard's telling me: http://take.ms/gpsoZ

Code is at: http://play.golang.org/p/oFjmBKfXgA

Comment: No, this is not normal. If you post your code, maybe someone can suggest an optimization.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin updated question to have code. What sort of latency do you get usually?

Comment: 50-150ms depending on a query.

Comment: Do you access it from a gae instance? If so, which datacenter was it spun in?

Comment: I do access from GAE, and it does not matter which datacenter as you measure "inside" time to retrieve, not a latency to a user.

Comment: When I look at trace list on gae ui, it's about 50-70ms which isn't that bad. Let me spin up a gae instance and check the latency there. How much latency do you get between the instance and data center?

Comment: Instances live in a datacenter. I am not sure what you mean by "between".

Comment: I meant how long does it take for entire query to complete, not just time on datastore, ie http roundtrip, token auth etc.The same code takes around 160-200s to run on an instance in gae, better than original, but still a little high.

Comment: If you're on appengine, there doesn't seem a good reason to be using the cloud-datastore api rather than appengine/datastore: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/

Comment: Is there a difference between the two? At this point I'm just evaluating different options so I wrote the above script to access the datastore api. Are you saying deploying an Go app via appengine or computengine and using appengine/datastore would result in better response times?

Comment: Turns out there's a difference: http://take.ms/qJOgC . Thanks @Greg. This new datastore has less than 10 entries, but I don't think that makes a difference.

Comment: You guys should make it a solved answer :)

Answer (score 3):

As [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1916/greg) pointed out, if you're on the App Engine, using Cloud Datastore API might not be the way to go. Rather, use the [appengine datasto](http://%20cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore)re directly